# Clang - how to retrieve "Expr" as string?

Tags: clang, llvm-clang, libtooling

I am using Clang/libtooling (`ASTComsumer` with a Matcher) to visit ALL `return` statements (`ReturnStmt`). I need to extract the expression that comes after the keyword `return` in a string form so that I can put that in a macro that I am replacing `return` statement with.

For example, I want to replace the following line:

```
return somefunc() + 1;
```

with

```
FUNCTION_EXIT(somefunc() + 1); // FUNCTION_EXIT is a C macro
```

The macro will `return` from the function after doing some logging.

I am using `ReturnStmt::getRetValue()` that returns an `Expr` and tried to get it in string form (so that it can be passed to the macro), but I haven't found a way yet. Is there a way to stringify `Expr`?

Answer (score 9):

Clang has a strict separation of concerns between the abstract syntax tree (AST) and the actual source code. The component that converts between these is the [Lexer](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Lexer.html). To get the raw source for an `Expr e:`

```
const string text = Lexer::getSourceText(e.getSourceRange(), source_manager, opt);
```

Note that the SourceManager and LangOptions are available from the [ASTContext](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ASTContext.html). If the code you're parsing has macros then things get more complicated because you have to care about spelling location versus expansion location; [SourceManager](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html) has a bunch of different functions to convert between these.

Good luck!

Comment: Just a note, I believe we need to do `CharSourceRange::getCharRange()` on the source range to work for `getSourceText`, and there's no implicit conversion between StringRef and string. otherwise this is how I did it as well :)

Comment: I don't know the difference between `getCharRange` and `getTokenRange`, but in my case, the latter works for me. Some identifiers are missing if I use `getCharRange`.